# How to check AWS SAM templated needed permission for deploy instead of seeing error?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have AWS SAM project ready for deployment. `sam deploy`

I have run `sam deploy` sometimes before, that it needs extra permissions sometimes. I keep adding new services into the template. Is there any way it can list all the permission it needed for the deploy? (Instead of deploying, then failed, then add the permission, and do it again?)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such tool today.

If your environment follows a permissionless approach, you don't have elevated or admin permission to deploy your stack directly, it is a "best effort"/guessing game you need to do based on the resources you defined.

You have permissions for the deployment of the stack (execution role) and between resources (resource or identity policies).

In this page in the AWS SAM documentation, they offer mechanism to simplify the provision of permission between resources and best practices:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-permissions.html

But in the end of the day, you need to define/know them upfront before deploying.

---

Similar question on [AWS: How to find out minimum required IAM permissions for GitHub Actions integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756440/aws-how-to-find-out-minimum-required-iam-permissions-for-github-actions-integra)

> You can however look at the Cloudtrail logs to see which actions are being invoked by CloudFormation, and based on that you could put together the list of required policies.

> Alternatively, you could replicate what the CloudFormation template is doing by using the AWS CLI. That way, you could use [iamlive](https://github.com/iann0036/iamlive) to generate the IAM policies required for those CLI commands.